# ng-show is not working using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i want to check condition on button in angularjs.and i am used ng-show but it is not working.

here i have write this code :

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Action').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {

            return <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Edituser(' + full.id + ');">Edit</button>' +
'<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="'+full.isdelete  == true+'" ng-  click="Enbleuser(' + full.id + ');">Enble</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="'+full.isdelete == false+'" ng-click="Disbleuser(' + full.id + ');">Disble</button>';                
        })
```

any one know please let me know.

Comment: Can you fiddle it?

Comment: i am just listing user using datatable in angularjs and this is my last column in the table and i have return the 2 button but isdelete == true then show just enble and isdelete == false then show disble button. and i get value full.isdelete in true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Action').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
        var editBtn = '<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Edituser(' + full.id + ');">Edit</button>';
        var enableBtn = '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="Enbleuser(' + full.id + ');">Enable</button>';
        var disableBtn = '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="Disbleuser(' + full.id + ');">Disable</button>';

        if (full.isdelete) return editBtn+enableBtn;
        else return editBtn+disableBtn;     
})
```

Comment: but here one more button is there for edit records then how can manage?wit i m edited my qus.

Comment: hi now can you please let me know how can manage this condtion?

Comment: I updated my answer. not sure if it's working for you or not, please check